# How to display a user form when an error occurs

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have an Excel-VBA user form which is used to get user input. I need to display this user form when an error occurs so that the user can redefine the input value.

Pseudo-code:

```
Sub ()
    userform.Show
    Call Execute
End Sub

Sub Execute()
    Validate the input
    If input is wrong
    MsgBox "reselect the input"
   -here I need to disply the userform-
End sub
```

I tried `GoTo Userform` which gives me a Label Not Defined error. Any suggestions?

Comment: your question is a bit unclear, incomplete, looks like you want us to write too much code for you. If you really ask for `On Error` solution search for `[VBA] On Error GoTo` here in SO or check [THIS LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251688%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I have created a UserForm :

[image]

On command button click, the code checks for the input, and if the input is wrong, it displays an error in message box and then redirects to the userform.

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

```
If TextBox1.Value = "" Then

    MsgBox ("Please provide the value")

    UserForm1.Show

    UserForm1.Repaint

End If
```

End Sub

**PS : Change the ShowModal property of the Userform to "False".**

[image]